# How to check if JSON object contains values

Tags: objective-c, json

I have a JSON array that I parse. I parse the values from the key `Staff`, however sometimes the `Staff` object contain no values;

Expected return;

[image]

But sometimes it returns:

[image]

Which causes the app to crash because `key[@"staff"][@"staff_id"]` doesnt exist.

Ive tried:

```
if (key[@"staff"][@"staff_id"]){
     //Parse staff 
}
else{

    //staff is empty

}
```

But this crashes as well because I think it still looks for the `[@"staff_id"]` which doesnt exist.

I've also tried

```
if (![key[@"staff"][@"staff_id"] isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]])
```

And

```
if (![key[@"staff"] isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]])
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a great example of shitty backend.
On the first example [image] staff is a Dictionary, on the second example  [image] is an Array.

You need to ask your backend developer, to decide and always return either Array, or Dictionary.

BTW, you can workaround it

```
if ([key[@"staff"] isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]] && key[@"staff"][@"staff_id"]) {
    id staffId = key[@"staff"][@"staff_id"];
} else {
    // Staff is empty
}
```

Comment: I would add to the if condition && [key objectForKey:@"staff_id"] just in case since returned JSON seems unconsistent

Comment: @NickCatib fixed, DevC that's great :) , if it fixed the problem, please mark it correct for further readers.

Comment: @l0gg3r had to wait a few mins before I could accept according to SO, but all working thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You will only get object of class NSNull if the JSON contained a null value. For example a dictionary { "key": null } will contain a key/value pair with a key "key" and a value [NSNull null]. Instead of using "isKindOfClass" you can compare with [NSNull null], because there is only ever one NSNull object. If your JSON doesn't contain null values, that won't happen.

If your JSON sometimes contains a dictionary, and sometimes an array, well that's tough. Blame the guys creating the JSON. You can write for example:

```
id keyObject = ...; 
NSDictionary* keyDictionary = keyObject; 
NSArray* keyArray = keyArray; 

if ([keyDictionary isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
    .. you've got a dictionary
} else if ([keyArray isKindOfClass [NSArray class]]) { 
    .. you've got an array 
} else if (keyObject == nil) {
    .. there wasn't actually any key object
} else if (keyObject == [NSNull null]) { 
    .. your JSON contained "key": null
} else {
    .. your JSON contained a string, number, or boolean value
}
```